# TextField not showing where it should be

Tags: positioning, textfield

I want to create a flyer using Latex. So I intend to have a foldable piece of paper with DinA5 pages. But I also intend to use a slightly modified version as a fillable online version. The plan is to have fillable boxes. But there everything goes down, as the boxes do not appear where I would like to have them. I want them to appear next to the discription (of what to put into them). At the moment they appear about 5 cm above the actual paper. Best way to see this is using Adope reader as he displays them correctly. Foxit and the inbound reader fo Texmaker only display them when I create a bunch of textboxes so that they are pushed into the normal page and thus become visible. The boxes are aligned in the correct way to each other but not alligned to the text at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,landscape,border shrink=5mm]
\usepackage[a4paper , left=2cm, right=2cm, top=1.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{float}  

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{\fontfamily{#1} \fontseries{#2} \fontshape{#3} \selectfont}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \AtTextCenter{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{4mm}
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{.5mm}
    \makebox(0,0)[c]{%
      \fbox{\rule{0pt}{\textheight}\rule{\textwidth}{0pt}}% Rahmen
    }%
  }
}



\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}


\textbf{  Informationen über den Teilnehmer }  \\
\raggedright
\TextField[name=Vorname, width=8cm,  bordercolor={green}, borderstyle=D, value={}]{Vorname:}

  \TextField[name=Nachname,width=5cm,  bordercolor={red}, borderstyle=D,
value={Muster}, backgroundcolor=lightgray]{Nachname:}   \\ 


\TextField[name=Straße,width=5cm,  bordercolor={gray}, borderstyle=D, value={}]{Stra\ss e:}
 \TextField[name=PLZ,width=2cm,  bordercolor={gray}, borderstyle=D, value={}]{PLZ:} \\ 

\end{document}
```

[image: picture of the problem displayed in Adobe]

Comment: don't use pgfpages and \pgfpagesuselayout  along with such textfields, that simply doesn't work.

Comment: You are right the problem is pdfpages. Is there any other way to archive what I intend to do or will I have to get rid of the texfields and replace them with something handmade?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do, but why don't you use simply twocolum?

Comment: What I was trying to archive was a document which had two pages per sheet which are each framed by a black line. Easyest solution would of course be to make a normal document and use a pdf printer to print it that way. But i had problems with the boxes not beeing displayed with even distances to the outsides of the paper because print to pdf is not custamisable. As ths pdfpages package caused so much harm I figured out I would beter use the  method discripted and just get latex to put the boxes differently. I was able to produce okay results this way. Tthank you for your time and answer.

Comment: Twocolum does not work with the boxes set via esopic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
%Language
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%Fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{\fontfamily{#1} \fontseries{#2} \fontshape{#3} \selectfont}
%Layout
\usepackage[]{multicol} % better than two column as it easily 'wraps' second column
\usepackage[landscape, top=1.3cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry} % outer margins
\setlength{\columnsep}{4cm} % inner margin = double outer

% AVOID \usepackage{pgfpages} % AVOID 
% AVOID \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[border shrink=5mm]
% Enhancements
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{xcolor}
% Handling
\usepackage{float} % multicol may require the H mod­i­fier of the float pack­age
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \AtTextCenter{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{4mm}
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{.5mm}
    \makebox(-435,0)[c]{%
      \fbox{\rule{0pt}{\textheight}\rule{0.4\textwidth}{0pt}}% Rahmen
    }%
    \makebox(410,0)[c]{%
      \fbox{\rule{0pt}{\textheight}\rule{0.4\textwidth}{0pt}}% Rahmen
    }%
  }
}

% Hyperref last before glossaries
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter 
\def\flushboth{% recommended de-ragged (\justifying) command from https://texfaq.org/FAQ-flushboth
  \let\\\@normalcr
  \@rightskip\z@skip \rightskip\@rightskip
  \leftskip\z@skip
  \parindent 1.5em\relax}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mwe demonstration only

\begin{document} \begin{multicols}{2}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\textbf{  Informationen über den Teilnehmer }\\

\raggedright
\TextField[name=Vorname, width=8cm, bordercolor={green}, borderstyle=D, value={}]{Vorname:}\newline
\TextField[name=Nachname, width=5cm, bordercolor={red}, borderstyle=D, value={Muster}, backgroundcolor=lightgray]{Nachname:}\newline
\TextField[name=Straße, width=5cm, bordercolor={gray}, borderstyle=D, value={}]{Stra\ss e:}
\TextField[name=PLZ, width=2cm, bordercolor={gray}, borderstyle=D, value={}]{PLZ:}\newline

\flushboth % =justifying
\vspace{0.5cm}
\lipsum [1-4]

 \end{multicols} \end{document}
```